# Celery-Beat: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN

Tags: python, django, docker, rabbitmq, celery

I'm getting an error on the celery-beat container.

**Celery-Beat Error Logs:**

```
[2018-11-27 12:40:21,139: WARNING/MainProcess] (0, 0): (403) ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
[2018-11-27 12:40:21,241: WARNING/MainProcess] Sentry is attempting to send 1 pending error messages
[2018-11-27 12:40:21,241: WARNING/MainProcess] Waiting up to 10 seconds
[2018-11-27 12:40:21,241: WARNING/MainProcess] Press Ctrl-C to quit
celery beat v4.0.2 (latentcall) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
LocalTime -> 2018-11-27 12:40:19
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://RabbitUser:**@rabbit:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> celerybeat-schedule
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
```

**RabbitMq Logs:**

```
=INFO REPORT==== 27-Nov-2018::12:40:19 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.308.0> (192.168.48.3:36552 -> 192.168.48.4:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 27-Nov-2018::12:40:24 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.313.0> (192.168.48.2:56664 -> 192.168.48.4:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 27-Nov-2018::12:40:24 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.313.0> (192.168.48.2:56664 -> 192.168.48.4:5672, state: starting):
AMQPLAIN login refused: user 'RabbitUser' - invalid credentials

=INFO REPORT==== 27-Nov-2018::12:40:24 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.313.0> (192.168.48.2:56664 -> 192.168.48.4:5672)
```

**According to the log, Is it an authentication error?**

When I try to curl It connecting to the rabbit successfully:

```
->curl -i -u RabbitUser:guest http://localhost:5672/api/whoami
  AMQP
```

**How can I solve this one?**

Comment: Yes, it looks like Celery is not able to authenticate against your RabbitMQ instance. Without seeing more of your configuration, it's hard to tell why.

Comment: Could you please tell me some Ideas, How can i solve this

Answer (score 5):

I assume you didnt create a rabbitMQ user named `RabbitUser` with a vhost `rabbit`:

Type this in your console:

```
rabbitmqctl add_user RabbitUser YOURPASSORDHERE
rabbitmqctl add_vhost rabbit
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags RabbitUser administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p rabbit RabbitUser ".*" ".*" ".*"
rabbitmqctl delete_user guest
```

This will create the user `RabbitUser` with the password you want, add the vhost `rabbit`, set your user administrator and give you the permission for the vhost `rabbit`

Comment: Should mention that this is necessary on master node only.