# django celery delay function use guest user

Tags: python, django, django-celery

Hello I want to use celery tasks in my Django project

When I run the `celery -A proj worker -l INFO` all good it connects to the rabbitmq server

But I have a problem when I run the task `add.delay(1, 1)` I get a response `(403) ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.`

In the logfile I can see `2022-01-16 23:15:51.898981+00:00 [erro] <0.1093.0> PLAIN login refused: user 'guest' - invalid credentials`
I understand celery delay function using the wrong user `guest` and not `saar`

my file in my project

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')
app = Celery('proj')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

settings.py

```
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://saar:1234567s@localhost'
```

**init**.py

```
from .celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

my packages: Django 3.2.11,
celery 5.2.3,
flower 1.0.0,
django-celery-beat 2.2.1

What can I do to fix it?

I found that if I import a task from the celery.py file before it works for me but how can i fix it if I only import from tasks.py file?

Comment: Can you connect to `rabbitmq` with this user?It seems like `rabbitmq` auth error not with `celery`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Celery-Beat: ACCESS\_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500587/celery-beat-access-refused-login-was-refused-using-authentication-mechanism-a)

Comment: My problem is not in the rabbitmq server the celery -A proj worker -l Info connects to the rabbitmq server with the Saar user